# SQLAlchemy Harvesine great circle calculation error

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following Table :

```
id     zip    city     state    longitude    latitude  timezone    dst
3817   99950    Ketchikan    AK    -131.46633      55.875767    -9           1
....
```

In my SQLALchemy Model I have the the below @classmethod 
I want to return all zip codes within X miles of a given lat,lon
I created two query but both query below failed query1, query2

```
@classmethod
def getZipsWithinXMiles(cls, lat1: str, lon1: str, dst: str):
    """ Get zip codes within 'dst' miles of lat1,lon1"""

    print(lat1, lon1, dst)
    breakpoint()
    query1 = "SELECT * ," \
        "( 3958.75 * acos(sin(lat1/57.2958) * sin(latitude/57.2958) + " \
        "cos(lat1/57.2958) * cos(latitude/57.2958) * " \
        "cos(longitude/57.2958 - lon1/57.2958))" \
        ") as distanceInMiles " \
        "FROM ZipCode " \
        "HAVING distanceInMiles < dst " \
        "ORDER BY distanceInMiles" \
        % {'lat1': float(lat1), 'lon1': float(lon1), 'dst': int(dst)}

    query2 = "SELECT * FROM " \
        "(SELECT id, city, state, zip, " \
        "( 3958.75 * acos(sin(lat1/57.2958) * sin(latitude/57.2958) + " \
        "cos(lat1/57.2958) * cos(latitude/57.2958) * " \
        "cos(longitude/57.2958 - lon1/57.2958))" \
        ") as distanceInMiles " \
        "FROM ZipCode " \
        " ) inner_query " \
        "HAVING distanceInMiles < dst " \
        "ORDER BY distanceInMiles" \
        % {'lat1': float(lat1), 'lon1': float(lon1), 'dst': int(dst)}

    print(query1)
    print(query2)
    breakpoint()
    zipCodes = cls.query.from_statement(query2).all()
    return zipCodes
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "zipcode" does not exist
LINE 1: ...57.2958 - lon1/57.2958))) as distanceInMiles FROM ZipCode  )...
```

Just for more information this is the model I used to create the table

```
class ZipCode(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "zipCode"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    zip = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)  # 23567
    city = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)  # New York
    state = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)  # Ex: NY
    longitude = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    timezone = db.Column(db.String(3), nullable=False)  # Ex: -5,-10
    dst = db.Column(db.String(2))  # Ex: 0,1
```

What is wrong with this code ?
I tried both queries and both failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
__tablename__ = "zipCode"
```

you will have to use a quoted identifier to refer to the table:

```
query1 = "..." \
    ...
    'FROM "zipCode" ' \
    ...
```

because of the [mixed case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other.

SQLAlchemy will use quoted identifiers, if the given [table name](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.name) contains upper case characters, is a reserved word, or contains special characters.

---

As to the rest, using `HAVING` clause to filter based on select-list items is a MySQL "extension" that Postgresql does not support. `query2` is on the right track in its use of a subquery, but should use `WHERE` clause instead.

It seems you've defined your `latitude` and `longitude` columns as strings, so you must use `CAST` in order to do arithmetic on them. Consider using proper types instead.

You've also used %-formatting, but without having any conversion specifiers in the string – which is a good thing, since you should not be doing string formatting anyway. Instead use bound parameters / placeholders and pass parameters to your SQL driver or library.

All in all your class method could look like:

```
def getZipsWithinXMiles(cls, lat1: str, lon1: str, dst: str):
    """ Get zip codes within 'dst' miles of lat1,lon1"""

    query = db.text("""
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT "zipCode".*
                 , (3958.75 *
                    acos(sin(:lat1 / 57.2958) * sin(cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) +
                         cos(:lat1 / 57.2958) * cos(cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) *
                         cos(cast(longitude as double precision) / 57.2958 - :lon1 / 57.2958)))
                   as distanceInMiles
            FROM "zipCode") zc
        WHERE zc.distanceInMiles < :dst
        ORDER BY zc.distanceInMiles
        """)

    zipCodes = cls.query.\
        from_statement(query).\
        params(lat1=float(lat1),
               lon1=float(lon1),
               dst=int(dst)).\
        all()

    return zipCodes
```

though I'll take no responsibility to correctness of the distance calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much . I will give this a try and get back to you . What is the reason I need to use quotes identifier to refer to table ?

Comment: I see you added the reason why the query was throwing and error. Indeed after I add a quoted identifier , the error disappeared. Still my query is not working but it should be because of another reason .Would you mind if I leave this open a little longer until I see the reason why it i s not working  now ?

Comment: What a beautifulness and elegance in your code !! What perfection and wiseness.
Thank you so much !!

Comment: I would like to add two more details to this :